# "^[" spamming across gnome terminal gnome terminal when a process is running

Tags: linux, keyboard, terminal, pop-os

a key sequence is being pressed by my keyboard occassionally.  At times  and I cannnot figure out for the life of me pressed shortcuts won't work.  I'm trying to nail down the key in particular and I know this will give me that exact info.

Using gnome terminal on Pop-os on a dell latitude e5550 when a process is running in the terminal, at times it the terminal will spam `^[...` like so `^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[^[` until I press another key.

I have attempted showkey... the problem has refused to present itself when showkey is running.

I pressed dozens of combinationes and haven't found the sequence through trial and error.

I've tried searching for the answer, but I can;t find anything, probably because I don't know what the name of the representations that show in the terminal are...

So what is the sequence that represents itself as `^[`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^` prefix generally means the next character ascii code should be reduced by 64. This is the behaviour of the Control key. (Type Ctrl-C sends the ASCII code #3 and is represented by `^C` Since this code has no representation. `^[` represents the ASCII code 27, Escapement. But I don’t know why it is spammed. (The last time I had a `^[` spamming was because of a water spill on the keyboard).

Comment: @mike : Not clear to me from the way you wrote it: Is it for sure that the spamming is triggered by some keypress? Because you wrote _at times it the terminal will spam_, and this could be understood that this occurs even when you had the fingers away from your keyboard.